# Windows 10 - pip says 'ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement setuptools>=40.8.0 (from versions: none)'

Tags: setuptools

We work in a closed network with limited access to internet, so no way of updating packages as I like. I recently made some changes to a package in use here and when I tried to install it with pip install , I got this error:       *ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement setuptools>=40.8.0 (from versions: none)
*

setuptools version is 68.0.0. The package was previously installed without any problem. pip and setuptools have been updated since then

Any help much appreciated

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.